# Default activity not created in Manifest file with Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

there maybe duplicate of this but I can't find any solution working for me.

I have downloaded latest Eclipse Juno from developer.android.com day before yesterday and it seems to act weirdly. I am trying to run "`Hello World`" but it is not creating default Activity in Manifest file.

Then I am also getting this error :

```
Unable to write Jarlist cache file
workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cacheworkspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
```

Can someone please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Manifest.

```
   <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand why is this happening. I already know this has to be done. Thx anyway.